# Anaesthesia and sleep

Tags: surgery, anesthesia

Having had two surgeries under general anaesthesia recently, I have been wondering... Being under general anaesthesia is physiologically not the same as sleeping. Sleep is needed in humans for restorative processes, a rule of thumb being 6 to 8 hours a day.

However, not all surgeries are like mine and only take one or two hours. Extreme cases, such as separating conjoined twins or complicated brain surgery may take a lot longer, even up to several days.

During and after long surgeries, is the lack of sleep a problem for the patient? How is it managed if this is (or would be) a problem?

Comment: Very interesting question that leads onto other questions that I'd like to ask.

Comment: Interesting but "Anaesthesia and sleep" is not a question. Can you rephrase the title into a question?

Answer (score 2):

You're right that sleep and general anesthesia are very different, and [general anesthesia in fact actively inhibits the glymphatic circulation](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5771087/) that clears waste products from the brain).  Since most of are able to pull an all-nighter and except for problems with memory, focus etc, be OK after a couple of days' catch-up sleep, the sleep deprivation isn't an acute issue -- after all, folks after major surgery tend to sleep a lot anyway, as the body needs extra sleep during healing.

As far as preventives, there is an ongoing study to see whether pre-operative cognitive training can reduce the odds of post-operative delirium, one of the ways in which temporary post-surgical cognitive dysfunction can be visible.

More seriously, there may be long-term costs of surgery, with or without anesthesia, on cognitive reserve. This is well-known for cardiac surgeries, but may also be true for any surgeries, as a cross-sectional study found that even the [lifetime number of non-cardiac surgeries one's had, correlates with reduced verbal learning and memory in one study of healthy older adults](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/31370773).

The general issue, called Post-Operative Cognitive Dysfunction (POCD) is an active area of investigation for older adult care. There seem to be multiple suspects - from inflammation to brain hypo-perfusion -- and each will suggest steps that can reduce the risk. A recent review is [Current Perspectives on Postoperative Cognitive Dysfunction in the Ageing Population](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/31828240).